# Is it possible in Latex to convert all numbers between imperial and metric?

Tags: units

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`smartunits`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartunits)

I am currently writing a document that I would like to deploy to both European and American audiences. The problem is, as usual, the choice between imperial vs metric units.

The text is not scientific, and not meant for a scientific audience, so I cannot simply use metric units all the way through and call it a day. Since many of the units are buried in the text, finding them all and changing them is quite cumbersome (even with the use of hidden comments as guiding flags).

What I am looking for is a method to offer the best out of both worlds. I am looking for something that can convert all metric units into imperial and vice versa. The ideal scheme would look like this:

```
\usepackage{smart_unit_package}

\smart_unit_convert{imperial}
...

\begin{document}
Oscar Wilde's height is said to have been \smart_unit{1.91}{meter}.
\end{document}
```

Which should hopefully result in:

```
Oscar Wilde's height is said to have been 6'3''
```

The idea behind it would be that the units can be controlled from the preamble, without having to alter the text.

Is there such a package available, or is it easily possible to create my own solution (I'm not that great at coding, and have never even tried writing anything in Tex before)?

I took a look at the siunitx package, but there is nothing in there about converting units back and forth.

Edit: As per Joseph Wright's comment, a few more details:
The units to convert would, at the minimum, be for weight, length, and time (with the last one optional, but advantageous). The conversion should be from standard metric (kilograms, meters, 24:00 format) to imperial (pounds, feet, 12 AM/PM format).

If I personally were writing a package, I would probably allow for certain command flags (e.g.: kilometer should translate to miles, not to thousands of feet), and body height (say 189 cm) should convert to 6'2'', not to "2 yards".

I realize that getting this right for every possible scenario (body height, mountain height, small distance, large distance, etc. etc.) is somewhat complex (mostly thanks to the weird parts of the imperial system).
As to accuracy: Since it is not written for a scientific audience, any rounding up to the decimal point is fine. I.e.: 1 meter can easily convert into 3 feet, even if it is not really exact. Of course, if more accuracy were needed, a roundoff-point would be necessary.

Second edit: A simple hack that I think might also work (even if it's not really elegant), is a way in latex to define two words. For instance:

```
Oscar Wilde's height is said to have been \twowords{191cm}{6'3''}.
```

With some possibility of choosing which one gets selected in the preamble. This would force the user to convert everything by himself, but it would allow easy swapping between units, at least.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! Whilst there is not to my knowledge a pre-built package for this it's entirely doable. Can you perhaps tighten up on the requirements, for example the exact units to convert, the nature of the conversions required, _etc._ (for example, for weights one might do kilograms to stone and pounds or just to pounds). Also, how accurate does this need to be.

Comment: Hi Joseph! Thanks for your comment. My mistake, I should have added all this information to begin with. I added it via edit, though I have started to realize that this might be more difficult than I first anticipated.

Comment: A problem with such an automatic conversion is that rounding is usually made. If someone weighs 76 kg, one would probably translate this into 12 stones, not 11 31/32 stones (or 11 stones 13.55 pounds). Similarly 6'3'' would become 1.90 meters, not the “more correct” 1.9062 meters. It's common in translations from English to translate “200 yards” into “200 meters“ (or “about 200 meters”), unless accuracy is really needed. So, a “200 yard path” would become “un sentiero di circa 200 metri” if I had to do a translation into Italian.

Comment: @egreg This is an excellent point: unless the context requires that precision, a simplistic conversion between units would yield weird, over-pedantic looking, sentences. For most text, the best approach to have a macro with the hack you describe, and you can add some kind of fuzzy checking.

Comment: @egreg Unless you're a government... In Canada you find signs like "No smoking within 7.62 m of this building." :)

Comment: The precision problem @egreg mentions exists also in an even worse form: IIRC, there was once a book titled "How to make a million dollars out of nothing" or the like, and someone translated that to another language and currency - using a currency conversion ratio with five digit precision! :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen “How to make 899 887.514 € out of nothing”

Comment: Suggestion: Use the metric system and provide them a table to lookup the data. This way they can learn something. Or, use one of the following examples and write sth like "1.91 m (6'3")"...

Comment: Sure that's possible, but TeX wasn't made for this. And just because [one country in the world hasn't yet transitioned to the metric system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrication_in_the_United_States) you want to adapt your paper to their needs?

Comment: @MartinSchröder

Um, yes, actually. Because that "one country in the world" is home to 300 million people.

And Latex also wasn't probably made to draw chemical formulas, yet there is a package for it.

Comment: @MarkAnderson, There is an important problem with this question and its answers.  Unfortunately it is likely beyond cleaning up at this point.  That is that the US collection of "customary units" (phrase favored by US's NIST) is _not_ the Imperial system. (The Imperial system was created in the early 1800s after the US had separated from Britain.)  The major difference is in units of capacity, where a US fluid gallon is about 3.8 L and an Imperial gallon is about 4.5 L.  It's over a 20% difference!  (And, of course, we have a set of units for capacity of dry goods that differs from both.)

Comment: Another comment I'll put on record (since your work is likely long since completed), is that you can most certainly use metric units in a document for an American audience.  We don't primarily use metric units, but they are certainly common enough.  The biggest trouble would be a lack of intuitive understanding of temperatures in degC, but everyone knows the 0 and 100 C points. Meters, liters, and kilograms are pretty well understood.  As are kilometers in the 3 to 10 range commonly used in running events.  (And @egreg, kilograms are _certainly_ better understood than stone!)

Comment: @dedded My solution below actually allow for the different "variations" in Imperial units that are used in the UK and the USA, at least with gallons (and the method easily extends to other units). I think that this was documented on TeX.SX when you wrote your comment but you will now have to look in the [smartunits](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartunits) documentation for details.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Implementing your hack is quite easy:

```
\newif\ifMetric\Metrictrue% metric by default
\newcommand\MyUnit[2]{\ifMetric #1\else #2\fi}% \MyUnits{metric}{imperial}
```

Then you can simply use `\MyUnit{191cm}{6'3''}` in your document and change between metric and imperial at any point using `\Metrictrue` and `\Metricfalse`.

Here's a full example  (with a crude use of [SIunits](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunits) as requested in the comments):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{SIunits}
\newif\ifMetric\Metrictrue% metric by default
\newcommand\MyUnit[2]{\ifMetric #1\else #2\fi}% \MyUnits{metric}{imperial}

\begin{document}
   Metric: \MyUnit{191 \centi\meter}{$6'3''$}

   \Metricfalse Imperial:  \MyUnit{191 \centi\meter}{$6'3''$}

   \Metrictrue Metric:  \MyUnit{191 \centi\meter}{$6'3''$}
\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image]

> **Edit: the smartunits package**

When I first wrote this post I said that it ought to be possible to do this properly using [pgfkeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). Partly as a proof-of-concept, and partly as an exercise to learn how to use `pgfkeys`, there is now a [smartunits](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartunits) package for converting between metric and Imperial units.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartunits}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
        texcsstyle=*\bfseries\color{blue},
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        commentstyle=\color{brown},
        morekeywords={SmartUnit,SmartUnitSettings,sisetup},
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}[texcl]
      \SmartUnitSettings{metric imperial, places=1}
      \SmartUnit{km=100.0,figures=1}   % \SmartUnit{km=100.0,figures=1}
      \SmartUnit{miles=62.15,places=1} % \SmartUnit{miles=62.15,places=1}
      \SmartUnit{cm=10}                % \SmartUnit{cm=10}
      \SmartUnit{celsius=20}           % \SmartUnit{celsius=20}
      \SmartUnit{miles=5.0, figures=1} % \SmartUnit{miles=5.0, figures=1}
      \SmartUnit{miles=5.0,places=2}   % \SmartUnit{miles=5.0, places=2}
      \SmartUnit{hours=0, minutes=59}  % \SmartUnit{hours=0, minutes=59}
      \SmartUnit{hours=12, minutes=12} % \SmartUnit{hours=12, minutes=12}
      \SmartUnit{kg=10.0, places=1}    % \SmartUnit{kg=10.0, places=1}
      \SmartUnit{pound=10.0,figures=1} % \SmartUnit{pound=10.0,figures=1}
      \SmartUnit{l=10.0, places=1}     % \SmartUnit{l=10.0, places=1}
      \SmartUnit{L=10.0, places=1,uk}  % \SmartUnit{L=10.0, places=1,uk}
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

and here is the output this produces:

[image]
(There is some trickery using the [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package to have LateX typeset the commands after the `%`'s on each line.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is already a huge step forward for me (you don't want to know how many units I would have had to manually switch). I'll flag this as the correct answer in the next few days if nobody comes up with the magical bullet package that I hope exists somewhere.

Comment: This hurts my eyes, you should use siunitx for the units or at least put a small space between number and unit `\,`

Comment: `:%s/\(\d'\d''\)/$\1$/g` for correctly typeset primes instead of the (curly) quotes

Comment: That's how I would do it. The next step may be to integrate it with `siunitx`.

Comment: @MarkAnderson I have added a proper "smart" interface.

Comment: @Andrew Amazing, simply amazing.Flagged you for correct answer.

Comment: @MarkAnderson I saw that you also wanted time so I have added this and put the code into a style file.

Answer (score 17):

For the sake of completeness, one option is to just do the unit conversions in LaTeX, using something like pgf/tikz or [fp](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fp?lang=en). I am personally of the opinion that this isn't an ideal solution, since there are a lot of edge cases (like, for instance, when to convert between meters and kilometers, or how much to round). It may be sufficient for a nonscientific use, though. With that caveat out of the way, here's a possible implementation.

First, we set up a flag to select between metric and imperial units.

```
\newif\ifmetric\metrictrue
```

We can then start by implementing a macro which switches between 24 hour time and 12 hour time, depending on the state of this flag. We'll assume that we input a time in 24 hour form, and convert it to 12 hour time if necessary.

```
\def\smarttime#1#2{%
  \ifmetric%
    #1:#2%
  \else%
    \ifnum#1>12%
      \FPeval{\result}{trunc(#1 - 12:0)}%
      \result:#2 PM%
    \else%
      #1:#2 AM%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
```

Basically, what this does is check if the first argument (the hours) is greater than 12. If it is, then it uses the fp package's `\FPeval` to subtract 12 from the number of hours. The time is then that new number of hours, followed by the minutes and PM. Otherwise, we just add an AM to the end of the time. This should actually completely work for your needs.

Next, let's do conversion between two units, say kilograms and pounds.

```
\def\smartkilogram#1{%
  \ifmetric%
    #1 kg%
  \else%
    \FPeval{\result}{round(#1 * 2.204:1)}%
    \result\ lbs%
  \fi%
}
```

Again we just do the math using `\FPeval` and use our flag to switch between metric and imperial units.

Converting between meters and feet plus inches is a little bit more involved, but not fundamentally different from how we did kilograms to pounds.

```
% Conditionally converts meters to miles/feet/inches
\def\smartmeter#1{%
  % Use metric units (meters)
  \ifmetric%
    \FPeval{\result}{trunc(#1:0)}%
    \ifnum\result>1000%
      \FPeval{\result}{trunc(#1/1000:1)}%
      \result\ km%
    \else%
      \FPeval{\result}{trunc(#1:2)}%
      \result\ m%
    \fi%
  % Use imperial units (feet and inches)
  \else
   \FPeval{\result}{trunc((3.281 * #1):0)}%
   \ifnum\result<5280%
     \FPeval{\result}{(3.281 * #1)}%
     \FPeval{\feet}{trunc((\result):0)}%
     \FPeval{\inch}{trunc((12 * ((\result) - (\feet))):0)}%
     \feet'\inch"%
    \else
     \FPeval{\feet}{trunc((\result):0)}%
     \FPeval{\miles}{trunc((\feet / 5280):1)}%
     \miles\ miles%
   \fi%
  \fi%
}
```

If you are working with kilometers as well, it might make sense to define something like this:

```
\def\smartkilometer#1{\FPeval{\result}{trunc((#1 * 1000):0)}\smartmeter{\result}}
```

What this does is it multiplies whatever number you give it by 1000 and puts that into the `\smartmeter` macro. It uses the name of the macro (`\smartmeter` vs `\smartkilometer`) to keep track of units.

With those macros defined, the following code:

```
\subsection*{Metric Units}
\metrictrue
Oscar Wilde's height is said to have been \smartmeter{1.91}.\\

Five kilometers is \smartkilometer{5}.\\

It is \smarttime{9}{00}. Later it will be \smarttime{13}{30}.\\

That ostrich weights \smartkilogram{100}!

\subsection*{Imperial Units}
\metricfalse
Oscar Wilde's height is said to have been \smartmeter{1.91}.\\

Five kilometers is \smartkilometer{5}.\\

It is \smarttime{9}{00}. Later it will be \smarttime{13}{30}.\\

That ostrich weights \smartkilogram{100}!
```

becomes this:

[image]

Comment: For what you're doing, I'd suggest using at most the time macro, and then instead doing the unit conversions by hand and doing something more like Andrew's solution. This "works," but it feels really messy and probably fails at edge cases like large or small values.

Comment: But 100 kg should be a over 200 lbs

Comment: ...why yes, it should. I've edited the answer to change the division by 2.204 to a multiplication by 2.204. I got the conversion backwards.

Comment: That solution looks very nice already! Thanks for taking the time to write it all!
May I add a small addendum? Since it is available, I suggest using the SIUnitX package for the metric units. This is makes it easier to typeset everything.

Comment: I had never seen SIUnitX before. It does look like a better way to do the units. I believe that all that would be needed would be to replace the lines that look like `\result km` with lines like `\SI{\result}{\kilo\meter}`.