# Typesetting Imperial units

Tags: siunitx, units

I'm writing a couple of documents that use Imperial units in them, and I'm curious as to whether there's a way to typeset the units when they are used in combination. Examples include:

- rendering 4 ft 8.5 in as 4′ 8½″
- correctly typesetting 9 mi 6 ch or 10 st. 3 lb

At the moment I've just piggybacked a number of extra commands onto `siunitx`, in a manner similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42087/how-to-typeset-imperial-us-customary-units-especially-in-combination-with-si-me), and this largely works to my satisfaction. I'm just a little stuck on trying to extend `siunitx` to handle these additional use-cases, without having to resort to manually inputting the appropriate spacing.

Comment: Well, neither imperial units nor Russian versts nor an Ell are SI units.

Comment: I would look at the way siunitx deals with angles...

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241169/is-it-possible-in-latex-to-convert-all-numbers-between-imperial-and-metric/